# Highcharts: tickInterval set in days?

Tags: highcharts

I need to set a tickInterval of 5 days and one of 13 days.
And I did this:

tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000  * 5 (5 days)
tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000  * 13 (13 days)

What I get instead is a tickInterval of 7 days when it's set to 5.
And a tickInterval of 14 days when it's set to 13.

Is there a way I could actually get what I need?

thx.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  @SebastianBochan, here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/SV7qy/..

Comment: It's already reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1104). According to answer, only multiples of ranges are supported, for example 1 week, 2 weeks etc. Use of tickPositioner is required in that case.